# javascript creating grid with string

Tags: javascript, string, console.log

I'm new to all of this and working through Eloquent JS. My goal here is a string that creates a chess board/grid of a given size, with spaces that consist of alternating hashes and blanks. I don't quite understand

1.) the correct solution to my problem

2.) what's happening when I make certain changes to the code

This seems like it should be the correct answer but the first line in the console isn't aligned properly because of the comma:

```
function chessBoard (size) {
result = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
    if ((i + j) % 2 == 0 ) {
      result = result + "#";        
  } else {
    result = result + " ";
    }

 }

result = result + "\n"
}
console.log(result);
}  

chessBoard(8);

"# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
"
```

If I change all 3 result statements inside the loops so the hash, space, and newline get placed on the other side of the + operator (result = "#" + result), the function produces:

```
"
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #"
```

That *looks* correct, but is it? Why does the first line start with a hash? If the inner loop is checking to see if (i + j) is even--last character is (1+8) right?--and then using

```
result = " " + result;
```

to add the last character to the string, why isn't that character at the beginning of the string?

Lastly, if I use the result = result += order for the statements in the inner loops, but result = "\n" + result in the outer loop, I get this:

```
"







# # # #  # # # ## # # #  # # # ## # # #  # # # ## # # #  # # # #"
```

What is happening here? Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Would you please show us a sample answer. What is the expected result, what input needed before running.

Comment: The grid is supposed to look like the pattern in my second example.

Comment: But your code is already producing the pattern in your second sample. I'm quite lost here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

```
function chessboard(size){
    var i=0, _size=size*size, output='';
    for(;i<_size; i++){ 
        // add a new line if we need two
        if (i % size === 0)
               output= output +'\n' ;

        // determine whether we need a hash or a space
        output = output + (i%2 ? '#': ' ');     
    }
    // append a new line at the end for proper formatting.
    return output + '\n'
}
```

2)
As you said the first line isn't aligned correctly because of the quote, so you need to add a new line character to the beginning.

in the second set what you're doing is prepending to the string essentially building it backwards. after each execution instead of adding the # or ' ' at the end of the string you're putting it at the beginning. At the end you prepend the newline character to the beginning of the string which makes it start on a new line.

Comment: Given the fact I'm building it backwards, why does it begin with the hash? I understand the inner loop to produce a 9, and therefore a blank space for the last character--that gets put at the beginning-- in that situation. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: in the first loop i =1, and j=1 i+j=2 2%2 ==0 so it begins with a hash

Comment: In the second one? It builds from the back, right? So shouldn't the hash be the last character on the first line, instead of the blank space?

Comment: no x+x will always be even. So x+x%2 ==0 at in the last loop i will be 8 and j will be 8

Comment: ok, maybe i don't understand the double loops. i read it as j=1-8 while i =1, then j=1-8 while y = 2, etc.

Comment: i=1, j=1, j=2, ... j=8 loop break, i=2, j=1, j=2, ... j=8 break, ect till i=8, j=1, j=2, ... j=8 break.  break out of outer loop.

Comment: i understood the loops correctly. maybe this is my issue: what are the i's and j's for the first and last characters of the first line?

Comment: first i=1, j=1 last i=1, j=8. when result = result + op. first i=8, j=8 and last i=8 j=1 when result = op + result.

Comment: ok, that's the source of my misunderstanding. last question: why is the i = 8 in the 2nd one?

Comment: because you're prepending to the string.  So on the last iteration your adding to the beginning of the string.

Comment: ah, so the same thing that's happening horizontally is also happening vertically? it's being built from right to left and bottom to top?

Comment: I think it would be better to think about it as being built from left to right in the first example and right to left in the second.  just imaging the \n as being a visible characters  in the string.

Comment: but aren't the i's vertical displacement? i didn't understand why the second example had i=8 on the first line

Comment: because the first line the the second example the string is being built backwards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to explain how the code in the solution works.

```
var size = 8;

var board = "";

for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
      board += "#";
    else
      board += " ";
  }
  board += "\n";
}

console.log(board);
```

So you have a loop in a loop here.  The first/outer loop controls the line break and the inner one controls whether a # or a ' '(space) gets printed (aka added to the board variable).

Basically, what helps me is to imagine the inner loop going wild and adding spaces and #
while the outer loop only really 'does' something (line break) every 8 times (or whatever the size variable).

So the inner loop runs and adds characters.  Meanwhile, the outer loop just increases the y size.  Every so often, it adds a new line to the board.

I'm working on visualizing for loops so that I can understand them better.

Answer (score 0):

*Why does the first line start with a hash?*

In the inner loop:

```
(i + j) % 2 == 0 ) 
   result = result + "#";
```

on the first run, `i` is `1` and `j` is `1`, so `1+1 = 2` and it happens that `2%2==0` so the condition is true and therefore you are going to get a # at the beginning.

Comment: But doesn't it matter whether it's result += " " or result = " " + result? I get the hash on the first run, sure, but on the last run shouldn't I get the blank? And if I'm using the second result statement shouldn't the blank space be the first character in the string?

Comment: I think it depends on the size that you start with, if it's even then you will end up with an even number since you start with i=1 and end with i<=size. Therefore the first condition will run one more time than the second.

Comment: I'm trying this from my firebug console, so I don't get any "" and it looks pretty aligned.

Answer (score 0):

I did some corrections using the Nimnam's solution to achieve the exactly second example pattern (I added some extra comments in the code too):

```
function chessboard(size){
    // You have to multiply the (grid*1) * grid because the '\n' character. 
    // i.e If you have a 8 grid would need 72 grids (64 + 8 = 72) because each 
    // line would need a /n character, totaling 9 grids for each line.

    var i=0, _size=(size+1)*size, output='';
    for(;i<_size; i++){ 
        // add a new line if we need two
        // now we have to add +1 to the size because the 9º character;
        if (i % (size + 1) === 0)
           output= output +'\n' ;

        // determine whether we need a hash or a space
        // I inverted the character order to achieve the correct pattern
        output = output + (i%2 ? ' ': '#');     
    }
    // append a new line at the end for proper formatting.
    return output + '\n'
}
```

I hope it helps :)